# finding the multiplicative order of a $\alpha$ and prove that it can be divided by $31$ in $\mathbb{F}_{q}^{*}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $f$ be a irreducible monic polynomial of degree three in $\mathbb{F}_{5}[X]$ and let $\alpha$ be the zero of this f in an expanded field $\mathbb{F}_q$ of  $\mathbb{F}_{5}[X]$. Prove that the order of $\alpha$ can be divided by $31$ in $\mathbb{F}_{q}^{*}$.

So far i know that:

$\mathbb{F}_q \cong \mathbb{F}_{5}[X]/(f)\cong\mathbb{F}_{5}(\alpha)$.

So $\mathbb{F}_q \cong \mathbb{F}_{125}$ and $\mathbb{F}_q^{*}$ has 124 elements! and clearly #$\alpha$|124 so #$\alpha$|{1,2,4,31,62,124}.

The only problem is that i should prove that the order of $\alpha$ can't be $\{1,2,4\}$.

Any hints/tricks for this last problem?

Kees

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: try writing a polynomial satisfied by $\alpha$ based on the order of $\alpha$.  If the order of $\alpha$ is $1$, $2$, or $4$, can you contradict the fact that the minimal polynomial for $\alpha$ over $\mathbb{F}_5$ has degree 3?

Comment: I get it i think. If the order of $\alpha = 1,2$ we have the polynomials $X-1$ and $X^{2}-1$ which obviously aren't of degree 3. But the one with degree 4 isn't that obvious for me..

Comment: $X^4 - 1 = (X^2 - 1)(X^2+1)$.

Comment: yes that's true, but now we did proof the minimum polynomial can't be of degree 4, but this doesn't mean there is no minimumpolynomial of degree 3 right? At the other to $\alpha$'s i found a smaller minimimumpolynomial which contradict the fact that the mimimumpolynomial is of degree 3. But at degree 4, maybe there is a third degree mimimum polynomial which has our $\alpha$ as a zero?

Comment: If $\alpha$ is a root of $X^4-1$ then it is either a root of $X^2-1$ or a root of $X^2+1$, both of which have degree 2.  Since $2<3$ this contradicts the minimality of $f$.